# Can someone explain why the output is not as expected after state changes in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have trouble understanding React states and useEffect in this particular example.
I have 2 initial states, word which is initialized as empty string, and field that gets value from a function initField()

initField function returs concated string that is word + 'FIELD'

```
function initField(){
   console.log("CALLED")
    return word+ ' - '+ "FIELD"
  }
```

after changing states in useEffect hooks, I expected the output of the field to be "WORD - FIELD"
but the output I get is only "- FIELD"

I cant understand why is that happening, can someone give deep explanation ?

This is my full code

```
function App() {
 
  const [word,setWord]=useState('');
  const [field,setField]=useState(initField())

  function initField(){
   console.log("CALLED")
    return word+ ' - '+ "FIELD"
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    setWord("WORD");
    setField(initField());
  },[])  

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h1>{field}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: The values change on the next render - so functions like `useEffect()` run to completion with the old values. So initial value of `word` is `''`, then `useEffect()` runs, `setWord()` gets called **but `word` still has its old value**, *then* `setField()` gets called while `word` is still `''`

Comment: After setWord("WORD") gets called in useEffect, component rerenders for the first time and the initField should have the word 'WORD' instead of empty string.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a state using `useState` during a render, the value of the state isn't updated during the same render but until the next render. Assuming in the same render

```
    setWord("WORD");
```

`word` isn't updated immediately after this. Therefore

```
    setField(initField());
```

will still have `word` -> `''`, and the outcome still is  `- FIELD`

The proper way would be to initialize the value during `setState` --

```
  const [word,setWord] = useState('WORD');
```

Comment: If I  console.log(word) inside initField function, the output in the console will be
empty string and then
WORD

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can see the console logs here https://codesandbox.io/s/new-grass-fcs785?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Yes, I have added console log of a word insite initField function and it console logs first time "" and then the second time it logs "WORD".  I dont understand why